# returning same initial input when filtering dataframes' values

Tags: pandas

I have the following dataframe I have obtained from the read_html pandas' property.

```
A        1.48        2.64    1.02         2.46   2.73
B       658.4        14.33    7.41        15.35   8.59
C        3.76         2.07    4.61         2.26   2.05
D   513854.86         5.70    0.00         5.35  30.16
```

I would like to remove the rows that are over 150 so I did a`df1= df[df > 150]`, however it returns the same table.

Then I thought to include in the decimals in the route`route = pd.read_html(https//route , decimal='.')` and continues returning the same initial dataframe with no filters.

This would be my desired output:

```
A        1.48        2.64    1.02         2.46   2.73
C        3.76         2.07    4.61         2.26   2.05
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need:

```
print (df)
   0          1      2     3      4      5
0  A       1.48   2.64  1.02   2.46   2.73
1  B     658.40  14.33  7.41  15.35   8.59
2  C       3.76   2.07  4.61   2.26   2.05
3  D  513854.86   5.70  0.00   5.35  30.16

df1 = df[~(df.iloc[:, 1:] > 150).any(1)]
print (df1)
   0     1     2     3     4     5
0  A  1.48  2.64  1.02  2.46  2.73
2  C  3.76  2.07  4.61  2.26  2.05
```

Or:

```
df1 = df[(df.iloc[:, 1:] <= 150).all(1)]
print (df1)
   0     1     2     3     4     5
0  A  1.48  2.64  1.02  2.46  2.73
2  C  3.76  2.07  4.61  2.26  2.05
```

Explanation:

First select all columns without first by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
print (df.iloc[:, 1:])
           1      2     3      4      5
0       1.48   2.64  1.02   2.46   2.73
1     658.40  14.33  7.41  15.35   8.59
2       3.76   2.07  4.61   2.26   2.05
3  513854.86   5.70  0.00   5.35  30.16
```

Then compare - get boolean DataFrame:

```
print (df.iloc[:, 1:] > 150)
       1      2      3      4      5
0  False  False  False  False  False
1   True  False  False  False  False
2  False  False  False  False  False
3   True  False  False  False  False

print (df.iloc[:, 1:] <= 150)
       1     2     3     4     5
0   True  True  True  True  True
1  False  True  True  True  True
2   True  True  True  True  True
3  False  True  True  True  True
```

Then use [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for check if all values in row has `True`s
or [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for check if at least one value is `True`:

```
print ((df.iloc[:, 1:] > 150).any(1))
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool

print ((df.iloc[:, 1:] <= 150).all(1))
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Last first `Series` invert with `~` and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

Comment: Hi @jezrael thank you for your help so much! The problem I am facing is that when I try `df.iloc[:, 1:] > 150` brings out that all the columns are true , how do you think I could do to  overcome this issue?

Comment: Glad can help ;) Nice day!