# Change values in all columns to None for particular value in specific column in dataframe using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like below:

```
time                 c1        c2
1 2017-07-23 11:39:10  3.385661  3.193302
2 2017-07-23 11:39:20  3.157000  2.912690
3 2017-07-23 11:39:30  3.277145  3.124290
4 2017-07-23 11:39:40  3.126075  2.982679
5 2017-07-23 11:39:50  3.135766  2.985840
6 2017-07-23 11:40:00  3.166134  3.016147
7 2017-07-23 11:40:10  2.487507  2.256214
8 2017-07-23 11:40:20  3.348368  3.158728
9 2017-07-23 11:40:30  3.219001  2.996357
10 2017-07-23 11:40:40  2.862558  2.711170
11 2017-07-23 11:40:50  2.558438  2.346303
12 2017-07-23 11:41:00  3.338989  3.192018
13 2017-07-23 11:41:10  2.674149  2.496557
14 2017-07-23 11:41:20  3.523231  3.315889
15 2017-07-23 11:41:30  2.931527  2.740840
16 2017-07-23 11:41:40  3.078464  2.938004
```

Problem 1: I want to make values in C1 and c2 to None if it falls between two specific time ranges from time column.

For problem 1: what I tried to do is , get the index of all rows that falls between two specific time ranges and then change values:

```
index_list = df.ds[(df.ds >= start_time) & (df.ds <= end_time)].index.tolist()
```

Problem 1 I solved using :

```
start_time = '2017-07-23 11:40:20'
end_time = '2017-07-23 11:40:50'

df.loc[(df['ds'] >= start_time) & (df['ds'] <= end_time), df.columns!= 'ds'] = None
```

Please help me with problem 2

Now, how to use this index list to change values to None in all columns except time column.

Problem 2: Also, if 3.38 or any specific number comes in any column (except time column),I want to make that value to None. What is the  way to do these things? Please suggest.I'm facing hard time to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for change values to `NaN` and then [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html), but practically it is problematic, check also [this](http://floating-point-gui.de/):

```
#convert if not datetime
#df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

start_time = '2017-07-23 11:40:20'
end_time = '2017-07-23 11:40:50'
#select only column c1, c2
df.loc[(df.time >= start_time) & (df.time <= end_time), ['c1','c2']] = np.nan

#check floats
print (df.iloc[0].tolist())
[Timestamp('2017-07-23 11:39:10'), 3.3856610000000003, 3.1933020000000001]


df = df.replace(3.3856610000000003,np.nan)
print (df)
                  time        c1        c2
1  2017-07-23 11:39:10       NaN  3.193302
2  2017-07-23 11:39:20  3.157000  2.912690
3  2017-07-23 11:39:30  3.277145  3.124290
4  2017-07-23 11:39:40  3.126075  2.982679
5  2017-07-23 11:39:50  3.135766  2.985840
6  2017-07-23 11:40:00  3.166134  3.016147
7  2017-07-23 11:40:10  2.487507  2.256214
8  2017-07-23 11:40:20       NaN       NaN
9  2017-07-23 11:40:30       NaN       NaN
10 2017-07-23 11:40:40       NaN       NaN
11 2017-07-23 11:40:50       NaN       NaN
12 2017-07-23 11:41:00  3.338989  3.192018
13 2017-07-23 11:41:10  2.674149  2.496557
14 2017-07-23 11:41:20  3.523231  3.315889
15 2017-07-23 11:41:30  2.931527  2.740840
16 2017-07-23 11:41:40  3.078464  2.938004
```

Solution with [`difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html) for all columns without `time` and `np.isclose` function:

```
start_time = '2017-07-23 11:40:20'
end_time = '2017-07-23 11:40:50'
cols = df.columns.difference(['time'])

df.loc[(df['time'] >= start_time) & (df['time'] <= end_time), cols] = None

df[cols] = df[cols].mask(np.isclose(df[cols].values, 3.38566), None)
print (df)
                   time       c1       c2
1   2017-07-23 11:39:10     None   3.1933
2   2017-07-23 11:39:20    3.157  2.91269
3   2017-07-23 11:39:30  3.27714  3.12429
4   2017-07-23 11:39:40  3.12608  2.98268
5   2017-07-23 11:39:50  3.13577  2.98584
6   2017-07-23 11:40:00  3.16613  3.01615
7   2017-07-23 11:40:10  2.48751  2.25621
8   2017-07-23 11:40:20      NaN      NaN
9   2017-07-23 11:40:30      NaN      NaN
10  2017-07-23 11:40:40      NaN      NaN
11  2017-07-23 11:40:50      NaN      NaN
12  2017-07-23 11:41:00  3.33899  3.19202
13  2017-07-23 11:41:10  2.67415  2.49656
14  2017-07-23 11:41:20  3.52323  3.31589
15  2017-07-23 11:41:30  2.93153  2.74084
16  2017-07-23 11:41:40  3.07846    2.938
```

---

You can use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for `DatetimeIndex` and then select rows by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and set `NaN`.

Replace `float` value is a bit problematic, because precision. So help function [`numpy.isclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) with [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) for replace to `None` by `boolean mask`:

```
#if necessary convert to datetime
#df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df = df.set_index('time')

df.loc['2017-07-23 11:39:20':'2017-07-23 11:39:50'] = np.nan
df.loc['2017-07-23 11:40:20':'2017-07-23 11:40:50'] = np.nan
df = df.mask(np.isclose(df.values, 3.38566))
print (df)
                           c1        c2
time                                   
2017-07-23 11:39:10       NaN  3.193302
2017-07-23 11:39:20       NaN       NaN
2017-07-23 11:39:30       NaN       NaN
2017-07-23 11:39:40       NaN       NaN
2017-07-23 11:39:50       NaN       NaN
2017-07-23 11:40:00  3.166134  3.016147
2017-07-23 11:40:10  2.487507  2.256214
2017-07-23 11:40:20       NaN       NaN
2017-07-23 11:40:30       NaN       NaN
2017-07-23 11:40:40       NaN       NaN
2017-07-23 11:40:50       NaN       NaN
2017-07-23 11:41:00  3.338989  3.192018
2017-07-23 11:41:10  2.674149  2.496557
2017-07-23 11:41:20  3.523231  3.315889
2017-07-23 11:41:30  2.931527  2.740840
2017-07-23 11:41:40  3.078464  2.938004
```

Comment: I do not want to make time column as index column. and I do not want to make use of isclose() as I'm looking for exact values

Comment: Can you explain more? If use `float`s what is precision?

Comment: exact no. I will give as input so, no need to worry about precision. For eg: let's say input is 3.166134, then make 3.166134 to None in all columns except time column

Comment: As mentioned before I do not want to make time column as index column.

Comment: I couldnt understand your solution to problem 2.

Comment: Replace floats is problematic, because precision. The best try it. Need higher precision as displayed. So if need replace first value in first row, I need get float value. And if convert to `list`, this value is possible used for replaced. So better is use np.isclose.

Comment: How about this df.loc[df[df.columns!= 'time'] == float(3.16613),df.columns!= 'ds'] = None

Comment: Do you try it? the best is check it by `print (df == float(3.16613))` In my opinion it return all False values.

Comment: Yeah I want to know the way I have written this line; df.loc[df[df.columns!= 'time'] == float(3.16613),df.columns!= 'ds'] = None it's correct or not

Comment: Is it not correct, unfortunately :( More problems, main `float(3.16613)` never match because low precision.

Comment: What about this piece of code from above code syntax? df.loc[df[df.columns!= 'time'] . I sthis correct? how do check for precision then?

Comment: So, i used something like this :df.loc[df[cols].values == float(3.16613),cols] = None But I'm getting ERROR: too many values to unpack (expected 1)

Comment: Hmmm, I try explain for compare float (practically) need `is.close`. If dont want use this function how do you need replace floats?

Comment: In my opinion second solution is what you need. But I am curious, why do you think `numpy.close` is bad choice? Why dont need it? Thanks.

Comment: I try test `df.loc[df[cols].values == float(3.16613),cols] = None` And I get same error. It seems `loc` cannot works with this and need `mask` function.

Comment: alright, i think I can use your this solution. df[cols] = df[cols].mask(np.isclose(df[cols].values, 3.38566), None).  What is I want to delete all values greater than 3.38566 or less than 3.38566.Please suggest

Comment: I think you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43977518/2901002) for better explanation of `df  = df[((df[cols] <= 3.3) | (df[cols] >= 3.5)).all(axis=1)]` - it remove all rows if any values between `3.3 and 3.5`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1 I solved using :

```
start_time = '2017-07-23 11:40:20'
end_time = '2017-07-23 11:40:50'

df.loc[(df['time'] >= start_time) & (df['time'] <= end_time), df.columns!= 'time'] = None
```